# Hide div 24hr cookie javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, popup, hide

I would like a simple JavaScript code that will allow me to hide a certain div element when clicked for a predefined amount of time. To be a little more informative, I have a suggestions box that appears when the home page is loaded. What I would like is when the div close button is clicked it sets a cookie to keep the box div closed for 24 hours (1day). Simply said, when the div close button is pressed, the box div is hidden for 24 hours. Note: I have a javascript that allows the close button to close the box but it will load every refresh.

---

https://i.stack.imgur.com/du1pA.jpg

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! SO is for asking *questions*, not asking people to write code for you. If you make an effort on the above and run into trouble, ask questions about that (showing your code), and people will be very happy to help.

Comment: Sounds more like a request, not a question per se.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Although T.J. Crowder is right in his comment that stackoverflow is not here for writing your code... I wrote some code for you. Here's a solution using jQuery. In it you'd use a `<div id="popupDiv">...</div>` for the message and a link in it with id "close" to close the div.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // If the 'hide cookie is not set we show the message
  if (!readCookie('hide')) {
    $('#popupDiv').show();
  }

  // Add the event that closes the popup and sets the cookie that tells us to
  // not show it again until one day has passed.
  $('#close').click(function() {
    $('#popupDiv').hide();
    createCookie('hide', true, 1)
    return false;
  });

});

// ---
// And some generic cookie logic
// ---
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
  if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
  }
  else var expires = "";
  document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
  var nameEQ = name + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
  }
  return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
  createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

Here's a js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FcFW2/1/. Run once and then run again. The second time the popup does not show.

Comment: blah.js is the the file I save this data in?

Comment: I;m not sure what you mean? What data exactly. If you mean what to do with this code: create a .js file and include that in your page. Make sure that the id's of the popup and the close button match up.

Comment: that code doesnt appear to be working

Comment: Hmm, it works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/FcFW2/1/. Make sure to add a #popupDiv {  display: none; }​ so that the popup is initially always invisible.

Comment: it was that an the javascript link was not added, i did a view in incognito and think it works now, i am very much appreciative, www.computersolutions.spruz.com if you wish to see what i am about

Comment: for future viewers I was refering to "<a href="JavaScript:void(0)" id="close">"

Answer (score 2):

this should get you started: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

the following examples use the functions declared in the above link.

creating a cookie:

```
// when the div is clicked
createCookie('hideSuggestionBox', 'true', 1);
```

reading a cookie:

```
// when deciding whether to show or hide the div (probably on document ready)
if (readCookie('hideSuggestionBox') === 'true') {
    // do not show the box, the cookie is there
} else {
    // the cookie was not found or is expired, show the box
}
```