# Hide div for 2 hour cookie javascript?

Tags: javascript, cookies

i want hide div when the person click on it and show another div using cookies

this is work for me but it take 24 hour , i wana make it just 2 hour ?

[Hide div 24hr cookie javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674611/hide-div-24hr-cookie-javascript)

i want make it 2 hour not 24 hour :)

Comment: You see where it says `24*60*60*1000`, that's 24 hours times 60 minutes times 60 seconds times 1000 milliseconds. Now try to guess what to change to make that 2 hours instead.

Comment: so i must change it to 2*60*60*1000

Comment: Sure seems that way `

Answer (score 0):

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
  alert("3");
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + exdays * 60 * 1000);
  var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function checkCookie() {
  var username = getCookie("username");
  if (username != "") {
    alert("Welcome again " + username);
  } else {
    username = prompt("Please enter your name:", "");
    if (username != "" && username != null) {
      setCookie("username", username, 2);
    }
  }
}
```

The expression d.setTime(d.getTime() + exdays * 60 * 1000); calculates the expiry date in terms of minutes. 
setCookie("username", username, 120); here, 120 is total minutes.