# Show a DIV based on sessions until the user closes it

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies

I'm trying to show a DIV to the user until he/she closes it. Once the user clicks `close`, the DIV remains close for 24 hours.

This is the working code that shows once every 24 hours. However, I'm not sure how to add the click function:

```
<?php
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['cookie'])) {
        setcookie('cookie', true, time() + 3600 * 24); // Save a cookie for 1 day
        echo '<div class="slideshow"><span class="close">close</span>Hello World</div>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: You add a button inside the `slideshow` div that calls a JS function which in turn removes the `sideshow` div from the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // If the 'hide cookie is not set we show the message
  if (!readCookie('hide')) {
    $('#popupDiv').show();
  }

  // Add the event that closes the popup and sets the cookie that tells us to
  // not show it again until one day has passed.
  $('#close').click(function() {
    $('#popupDiv').hide();
    createCookie('hide', true, 1)
    return false;
  });

});

// ---
// And some generic cookie logic
// ---
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
  if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
  }
  else var expires = "";
  document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
  var nameEQ = name + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
  }
  return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
  createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

code taken from here.[SEE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674611/hide-div-24hr-cookie-javascript?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Thanks. Playing around with it to get it done in PHP. Marking your answer as correct.